# Using a custom DiskSpaceHealthIndicator (Spring Boot Actuator)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

My spring application.yaml:

```
management:
  ...
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: ALWAYS
    info:
      enabled: false
  health:
    diskspace:
      path: "some-path"
      threshold: 536870912
```

This will use the https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/system/DiskSpaceHealthIndicator.html to perform the health check.

I would like to extend/wrap `org.springframework.boot.actuate.system.DiskSpaceHealthIndicator` to add some application-specific behavior. Is there a way to configure my application to use my own custom version, e.g. `com.acme.myapp.CustomDiskSpaceHealthIndicator` instead of `org.springframework.boot.actuate.system.DiskSpaceHealthIndicator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply provide a custom bean with the name `diskSpaceHealthIndicator` and it will replace the default `DiskSpaceHealthIndicator`:

```java
@Configuration
public class DiskSpaceHealthIndicatorConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DiskSpaceHealthIndicator diskSpaceHealthIndicator(DiskSpaceHealthIndicatorProperties properties) {
        return new MyDiskSpaceHealthIndicator(properties.getPath(), properties.getThreshold());
    }

    private static class MyDiskSpaceHealthIndicator extends DiskSpaceHealthIndicator {

        public MyDiskSpaceHealthIndicator(File path, DataSize threshold) {
            super(path, threshold);
        }

        @Override
        protected void doHealthCheck(Builder builder) throws Exception {
            // Do whatever you need here
            super.doHealthCheck(builder);
            builder.withDetail("custom details", "whatever");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mafor, does `MyDiskSpaceHealthIndicator`  need to be a static inner class?

Comment: @Rory definitely no, it might be placed anywhere.