Spring MVC with Java Configuration; Don't know how to configure actuator to show http.server.requests
I'm trying to bring Actuator into a 'mature' Spring MVC application.
Currently (mostly) running OK on Spring 6.2.0-SNAPSHOT, Spring Boot 3.2.4, JDK 23 and Tomcat 10.1.20 (so all as up-to-date as I can make it).
Thanks to assists from other Stackoverflow pages (eg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75114844, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58059878/3631003, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63346256/3631003) along with other Good Stuff Sites (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators#extending-endpoints) I've got many useful features working with Java Configuration.
I just can't figure out how to enable HTTP usage metrics. Hence this question..
For reference, here is my current (work-in-progress) Configuration:
package my.config;

import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.beans.BeansEndpointAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.EndpointAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.CorsEndpointProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.WebEndpointAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.WebEndpointProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthContributorAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.info.InfoEndpointAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.*;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.simple.SimpleMetricsExportAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.observation.ObservationAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.system.DiskSpaceHealthContributorAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.system.DiskSpaceHealthIndicatorProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.ExposableEndpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.*;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.annotation.ControllerEndpointsSupplier;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.annotation.ServletEndpointsSupplier;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Health;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.info.*;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.system.DiskSpaceHealthIndicator;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ImportAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletPath;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/75114844

@Configuration
@ImportAutoConfiguration({
        EndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
        WebEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,

        HealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class,
        HealthEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,

        BeansEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,

        DiskSpaceHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class,

        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/58059878/3631003
        MetricsAutoConfiguration.class,
        SimpleMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class,
        CompositeMeterRegistryAutoConfiguration.class,
        ObservationAutoConfiguration.class,
        JvmMetricsAutoConfiguration.class,
        MetricsEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
        SystemMetricsAutoConfiguration.class,

        InfoEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
        // added to /info endpoint
        JavaInfoContributor.class,
        OsInfoContributor.class,
        // add properties beginning with info, eg: -Dinfo.env.stuff=hello
        // https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-info-endpoint/
        EnvironmentInfoContributor.class,
        BuildInfoContributor.class,

        // look into resources/META-INF/build-info.properties
        ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration.class,

})

@EnableConfigurationProperties(CorsEndpointProperties.class)
public class SpringBootActuatorConfig {

    // TODO: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators#extending-endpoints
    // TODO: Spring Boot 3.2 ships support for virtual threads. To use virtual threads, you need to run on Java 21 and set the property spring.threads.virtual.enabled to true.

    @Bean // taken from WebMvcEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class
    public WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping webEndpointServletHandlerMapping(WebEndpointsSupplier webEndpointsSupplier,
                                                                         ServletEndpointsSupplier servletEndpointsSupplier, ControllerEndpointsSupplier controllerEndpointsSupplier,
                                                                         EndpointMediaTypes endpointMediaTypes, CorsEndpointProperties corsProperties,
                                                                         WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties) {
        List<ExposableEndpoint<?>> allEndpoints = new ArrayList<>();
        Collection<ExposableWebEndpoint> webEndpoints = webEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints();
        allEndpoints.addAll(webEndpoints);
        allEndpoints.addAll(servletEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
        allEndpoints.addAll(controllerEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
        EndpointMapping endpointMapping = new EndpointMapping(webEndpointProperties.getBasePath());
        return new WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping(endpointMapping,
                webEndpoints,
                endpointMediaTypes,
                corsProperties.toCorsConfiguration(),
                new EndpointLinksResolver(allEndpoints, webEndpointProperties.getBasePath()),
                true);
    }

    @Bean
    DispatcherServletPath dispatcherServletPath() {
        return () -> "/";
    }


    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/63346256/3631003
    @Bean
    public DiskSpaceHealthIndicator diskSpaceHealthIndicatorForCDriveAt100Mb(DiskSpaceHealthIndicatorProperties properties) {
        return new MyDiskSpaceHealthIndicator(new File("C:/"), DataSize.ofMegabytes(100));
    }

    private static class MyDiskSpaceHealthIndicator extends DiskSpaceHealthIndicator {

        public MyDiskSpaceHealthIndicator(File path, DataSize threshold) {
            super(path, threshold);
        }

        @Override
        protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) throws Exception {
            // Do whatever you need here
            super.doHealthCheck(builder);
            builder.withDetail("custom details", "whatever");
        }
    }

    @Component
    private static class MyInfoContributor implements InfoContributor {

        @Override
        public void contribute(Info.Builder builder) {
            Map<String, Integer> details = new HashMap<>();
            details.put("active", 42);
            details.put("inactive", 88);

            builder.withDetail("myInfo", details);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    private static class ActuatorConfiguration {

        public ActuatorConfiguration() {
        }

        @Bean
        public HealthIndicator sampleHealthIndicator() {
            return Health.up()
                    .withDetail("info", "Sample Health")
                    ::build;
        }

    }
}

Example:

To get this working, I need to set a few system properties:
-Dmanagement.endpoint.info.enabled=true
-Dmanagement.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
-Dmanagement.endpoint.health.enabled=true
-Dmanagement.endpoint.beans.enabled=true
-Dmanagement.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
-Dmanagement.endpoint.health.show-details=always
-Dinfo.env.stuff=hello
-Dspring.threads.virtual.enabled=true

The metrics endpoint is active:

But http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests is not there:

The configuration of actuate 1 and 2 and 3 seems to be rather different and this adds to my confusion.
I THINK this link points the way(?): https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/observability.html
Anyone got this working?

Why the complex configuration? Why not let Spring Boot figure that configuration out for you, also don't upgrade to Spring Framework 6.2 as that hasn't been tested with Spring Boot 3.2 (which uses 6.1) so you will run into incompatibility issues somewhere. In theory the only thing you need to do is add spring-boot-starter-actuator and maybe add some configuration in your properties but not the contraption you have now.

Becase this is "...a 'mature' Spring MVC application." NOT a boot application. As such, it doesn't get all the 'magic' autoconfiguration that boot does for 'free.' I've given a number of references where other people have had/wanted to do the same 'contraption' :-)

Well it might even be easier to use Spring Boot here (for bootstrapping and the auto-configuration) but alas. You would need to setup the observability that Spring Boot does yourself, you would need to check the Mvc Autoconfiguration and metrics autoconfiguration for which components to add.
